# How would I print the line under a selected line of text from a .txt file? (python)

Tags: python, passwords, password-protection

So I am trying to make a password program that, when opened, would generate a password for a website I set, place said password in a .txt file, and then another file would be looking at that file for when I need that password. I figured out the workings for the password generator, but not for the password keeper. My current code looks like this:

```
    file = open('pass.txt')
    file.read()
    passID = input("Enter Site Name:\n")
    if(passID in file.read()):
        print(next(file))
    else:
        print("password not found")

givePassword()
```

The problem is that the program can't find the text in the .txt file (the word being "abc"). I'm also almost certain that I'm not using `next()` properly... Any help?

Comment: one time `file.read()` will read all the file and cursor will be at last position to re-read again you need to seek back at `0, 0` position. Rather store `file.read()` in variable and apply `if` condition on variable.

Comment: You need to assign the results of your first call to `file.read()` to a variable, then split it into lines, then search those lines. Your second call to `file.read()` is pointless, because it's already at the end of the file.